# Hamming distance matrix for multiple sequences

Tags: python, bioinformatics, hamming-distance

I have a FASTA file with IDs and corresponding DNA sequences which I have parsed and stored into a dictionary.
I now need to write a Python program compute the pairwise Hamming distance matrix for ALL sequences.

So far I've tried running a for-loop on all the values of the dictionary and checking each character but that doesn't properly implement the Hamming distance or return a matrix.

Comment: Have you tried Biopython? https://biopython.org/ I think the pairwise2 function is what you need http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.pairwise2-module.html

Comment: @alec_djinn I've reviewed that but I'm not sure how to apply it to more than 2 sequences. All the examples are just for 2 sequence alignments.

Comment: @user10520622 biopython is the right place to start, it should be pretty easy to put a `for` loop together that does what you've asked for. welcome to the world of code!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the sklearn package, it has a function to calculate pairwise distances with a specified distance metric. You can find the function here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html.