# How can I compare each row from a dataframe against every row from another dataframe and see the difference between values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df1

```
     Code     Number
0   ABC123      1
1   DEF456      2
2   GHI789      3
3   DEA456      4
```

df2

```
     Code 
0   ABD123
1   DEA458
2   GHI789
```

df1 acts like a dictionary, from which I can get the respective number for each item by checking their code. There are, however, unregistered codes, and in case I find an unregistered code, I'm supposed to look for the codes that look the most like them. So, the outcome should to be:

ABD123 = 1 (because it has 1 different character from ABC123)

DEA456 = 4 (because it has 1 different character from DEA456, and 2 from DEF456, so it chooses the closest one)

GHI789 = 3 (because it has an equivalent at df1)

I know how to check for the differences of each code individually and save the "length" of characters that differ, but I don't know how to apply this code as I don't know how to compare each row from df2 against all rows from df1. Is there a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55936811/hamming-distance-matrix-for-multiple-sequences).

Comment: unfortunately I can't get new packages or libraries for Python, so the sklearn solution doesn't fit for me...

a guy who used to work with me managed to create a logic that does exactly what I need, but I can't understand exactly what he did and thus I can't apply it elsewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> don't know how to compare each row from df2 against all rows from df1.

Nested loops will work.  If you had a function named `compare` it would look like this...

```
for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
        difference = compare(row2,row1)
        #do something with the difference.
```

---

Nested loops are usually not ideal when working with Pandas or Numpy but they do work.  There may be better solutions.

---

[DataFrame.iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
df['Code_e'] = df['Code'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
df2['Code_e'] = df2['Code'].str.extract(r'(\d+)').astype(int)
final_df = pd.merge_asof(df2,df.sort_values(by='Code_e'),on='Code_e',suffixes=('','_right')).drop(['Code_e','Code_right'],axis=1)
```